# I want to enable the 'root' user during the login prompt on Ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: root

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 Server version. I want to enable the 'root' user login. I have tried with /etc/ssh/sshd_config file but no positive results comes out.Please help me providing the solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use SSH to login or console login?

Answer (score 2):

You should set password of `root` user to enable it. Use this:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Comment: Yes I have done all this things, butresult is null.I want to enable the root user login in login prompt.

Comment: This command enable root user. Maybe some problem with permission or similar. What is inside of `/var/log/auth.log`?

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` you need to comment or delete the line `PermitRootLogin without-password`
After that, add the line `PermitRootLogin yes`
Finally restart the SSH with `service ssh restart`

Comment: Yes I have done all this things, butresult is null.I want to enable the root user login in login prompt.